# Iniciar com um <f:selectItem já selecionado

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Eu gostaria que quado o menu fosse apresentado o "Option 1" começasse selecionado, algo como um selected do html

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="basic" value="#{selectManyView.selectedOptions}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

No seu código Java você provavelmente tem algo assim:

```
public class SelectManyView{
    private List<String> selectedOptions;

    public List<String> getSelectedOptions() {
        return selectedOptions;
    }
}
```

No construtor da sua classe, inicie a lista com os valores que você quer que já venha selecionado. Algo assim:

```
public class SelectManyView{
    private List<String> selectedOptions;

    public SelectManyView(){
       this.selectedOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
       this.selectedOptions.add("1"); // é o campo itemValue do Option 1
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedOptions() {
        return selectedOptions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ele retorna os itens na lista normalmente mas não fica selecionado

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar o atributo `noSelectionOption`?

Exemplo:

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="basic" value="#{selectManyView.selectedOptions}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" noSelectionOption ="true"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Você adiciona o atributo `noSelectionOption` no item que você deseja já deixar selecionado. Lembrando que é necessário passar o valor de **true** para o atributo.